# Why are fees so high, what am I doing wrong

Tags: fees, wallet-transfer

I'm trying to transfer a small amount of ETH from one account to another. However the fees its sugesting are crazy. This can't be normal.

Firstly it asks for 1 ether, which is $470. Dragging the slider down and it asks for 0.05 ether which is still alot at $23.

Am I missing something? Is it a bug?

[image: ETH Bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug with the light mist wallet. Ran the full wallet and everything is okay.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/3348)